# Authorization based on multiple conditions

Tags: spring-security

When we write below code we restrict access only to user role ROLE_ADMIN.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

How to restrict multiple url based on multiple condition?
For Example: If we have a product application(say there are 10 products), Each user has access to only 3 products. Now my condition is, If user role is ROLE_ADMIN and has access to Product 1, 2, 5 then give authrozition else restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to handle field level security in Spring Security filters. Recommend to take a look at this [spring.io video](http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/12/springone2gx-2013-replay-getting-started-with-spring-security-3-2?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRokuKrAZKXonjHpfsX56eUqUKK0h4kz2EFye%2BLIHETpodcMT8NkMK%2BTFAwTG5toziV8R7bHKc1pz98QWxHr). Field level security is explained around time 1.00.00 (1 hour). Peter Humpfrey uses Java configs, but it shouldn't matter.